# Avoid UISearchBar resizing

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a `UITableView` as a `UIView` subview. This table view has a `UISearchBar`, which is working correctly, but it's changing it's position when it becomes first responder:

[image]

Code:

```
self.searchBar = [UISearchBar new];
self.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.searchBar.placeholder = @"Buscar";
self.searchBar.text = @"";

self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];
self.searchController.delegate = self;
self.searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
```

Is there anyway to avoid this change? I'd like it to remain at the same place when selected.

Thanks!

Comment: can you put some code so that we can understand where exactly the problem.

Comment: Are you using UISearchDisplayController?

Comment: @Ram edited the post with code, even though is pretty vanilla

Comment: use `UISearchBar` with search display comtroller

Comment: Is `displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar` set to `YES`?

Comment: Are you using SearchBarController? , user SearchBar that is better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution: http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2013/fixing-uisearchdisplaycontroller-on-ios-7/

UISearchDisplayController is pretty bad on iOS 7.